# How to split path and parameters in python flet?

Tags: python, flet

I tried to use `flet.page.query` to pass some parameters to the page, but ran into some problems. My `match page.route:` path handler reads the parameter string after the `?` part of the path string and I can't seem to separate them at all because it seems page.path is not a string.

Here's an example of the code I'm working on right now:

```
import flet as ft
import flet_fastapi


async def main(page: ft.Page):
    async def route_change(route):
        page.views.clear()
        match page.route:
            case "/page1":
                page.views.append(ft.View("/page1", [
                    ft.Text("page1")
                ]))

                print("---")
                print(page.query.get("test"))
                print("---")

    def view_pop(view):
        page.views.pop()
        top_view = page.views[-1]
        page.go(top_view.route)

    page.on_route_change = route_change
    page.on_view_pop = view_pop
    await page.go_async(page.route)

app = flet_fastapi.app(main)
```

Thank you in advance=)

Comment: Have you tried casting `page.route()` to a string, printing that, and seeing if you can create a match criterion using that? e.g.: `str(page.route())`? I am not a `flet` expert. 

Surely there is a way to decompose that value into something usable?

Comment: @CaffeineDependent I tried this and it works. But I would like to know if perhaps there is a more correct approach provided for in the documentation